# GNOME session-manager fails to recognize inhibitor

Tags: debian, gnome

If GNOME applications have unsaved data and the user wants to shutdown or logoff, the session manager informs the user about this (never mind the "not responding" in the screenshot):

[image: illustration]

I believe that this is done via dbus, see [here](http://www.lucidelectricdreams.com/2011/06/disabling-screensaverlock-screen-on.html) and [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62820/how-to-find-out-which-unknown-program-is-still-running-and-preventing-shutdown).

#### Question

I can successfully register an inhibitor using the python example from the [first link](http://www.lucidelectricdreams.com/2011/06/disabling-screensaverlock-screen-on.html).
But the inhibition and the "reason" is not shown during log out. Why?

System is Debian 7 using GNOME 3.4

Answer (score 0):

The `Inhibit()` call has a flags-parameter. You don't show any of your code so we can't tell what value you used but I'm guessing it's not the right one.

GTK+ applications have a nice API they can use for this in [gtk_application_inhibit()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#gtk-application-inhibit).

The SessionManager D-Bus API is not declared stable but using that *if it's available* should be fine if you can't use GtkApplication. These are the flag values (bitwise OR'd together) for the SessionManager API:

```
1: Inhibit logging out
2: Inhibit user switching
4: Inhibit suspending the session or computer
8: Inhibit the session being marked as idle
16: Inhibit auto-mounting removable media for the session
```